# IEditableCollectionView to filter out deleted objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, crud

I'm using my own derived `ObservableCollection` that implements `ICollectionViewFactory` to allow me to create my own `IEditableCollectionView` on top of it. The (main) purpose of the view is to allow filtering out objects flagged as "deleted", so that these records aren't shown to the user but still remains within the collection, as long as they're not marked as "accepted" or rolled back.

Am I on the right track here? Or this isn't the purpose of `IEditableCollectionView`?

**UPDATE:** The collection must support adding, removing and editing records.

**SECOND UPDATE:** The records flagged as "deleted" must still be within the source collection, as a delete operation can be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after can be achieved much more easily

Say you have a *Model*

```
public class Item
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And your *ViewModel* contains a collection

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems { get; set; }
```

You can add `ICollectionView` property that will filter your collection by undeleted items. Here is an example:

```
public ICollectionView UndeletedItems { get; set; }
```

Filtering logic:

```
// Collection which will take your ObservableCollection
var itemSourceList = new CollectionViewSource { Source = MyItems };

// ICollectionView the View/UI part 
UndeletedItems = itemSourceList.View;

//add the Filter
UndeletedItems.Filter = new Predicate<object>(item => !((Item)item).IsDeleted);
```

Then bind your *View* to `UndeletedItems` instead

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UndeletedItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This will hide deleted items while still supporting CRUD operations.

Hope this helps

Comment: forgive me if syntax is a little off I wrote it from memory. Also, I disregarded `INotifyPropertyChanged` just for example sake.

Comment: I updated the question to point out that the collection must still support classic CRUD operations. Unless I'm mistaken (I'm new to WPF after all), in your scenario the UndeletedItems will return an enumerable that won't allow a grid to add or remove records.

Comment: @Crono1981 Can't test it or play around with it at the moment but I'll test it tomorrow once I'm in front of Visual Studio and update my answer accordinly.

Comment: @Crono1981 Updated my answer. Hope it would help :)

Comment: Well that IS a great answer, but unfortunately I don't think I can do things that way. The UndeletedItems view's AddItem method will create a new record by invoking it's default constructor rather than using my own record factory. That's a major problem. I need every new records to be created by the source collection, as it holds default field values logic.

Comment: @Crono1981 Sorry mate, I'm out of idea's :) Regardless I think you should upload your code so it would be easier to help you

Comment: It would be hard to upload my code because it depends on lots of other code. Besides, I'm giving up on this. I'll use a derived BindingList<T> that will keep an inner collection of deleted records, so they can be rolled back in at any time. Thanks for your help, though.